# React-Native parent Node change children value

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am looking for all web but I no found any solution, maybe because I am newer with React-Native universe.

Well, my question is about Node Parent change value of Children.

My situation is, I have a data controller and this data controller listen data from events and when the events happen it need update a component like Slider.

the render need be.

```
<DataListener url={this.state.service_url}>
    <Slider style={this.styles.slider_component}/>
</DataListener>
```

I need understand the cycle to get a default `Slider` with my `Class DataListener`. Is it with props in constructor? How can I get the slider inside `DataListener` and change this value like `this.default_slider.value = 0.4`

Thanks Advance
Victor C Tavernari

Answer (score 0):

You should pass down the value as a prop and then your slider component can deal with it appropriately.  Of course DataListener has to get the value in the first place and as you have detailed that let's assume it is in state (when you update state (via this.setState(newState)) it will cause a re-render of the DataListener which will in turn re-render the Slider with the new property):

```
<DataListener url={this.state.service_url}>
  <Slider style={this.styles.slider_component} value={this.state.value}/>
</DataListener>
```

the data controller event you refer to would then be something like

```
onEvent(e) {
  this.setState({value: e.value});
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation about the cycle. But I want know, How DataListener can manipulate the Slider? Or is impossible do it?

Comment: It's not exactly impossible just not really the React way of doing things.  Firstly a component can't directly affect another component but it can call methods on another component (or as per my original answer pass it props which usually makes more sense).  If that component is a child component then the easiest way is via a ref : https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html.  In order to affect the child component the child component would need to contain a method and the parent component would call that component via a ref

Comment: I've added a simple handler to show what you would do to trigger an update via state - it is the way that React is designed to work and much more likely to be what you want to do in the end